# Endless program execution

Tags: python, algorithm

Task: It is necessary to output a chain of words so that the next word begins with the last letter of the previous word.

Input Example: `"aac", "cas", "baa", "eeb"`

Example output: `"eeb", "baa", "aac", "cas"`

When using a large number of words (~ 980), the program goes into an endless loop. 
I think the problem is here, but I can’t solve it:

```
for j in range(0,N-U):
    if (s[j][0] == words[i][-1]):
       searchNextWord(s,j,U)
```

Code:

```
def searchNextWord(words,i,U):
        global Result
        s = [None]*N
        if (Result==True):
            return
        res[U] = words[i]
        U += 1
        if (U == N):
            Result = res[U - 1] == words[i]
        if (Result==True):
            return

        for j in range(0,N-U):
            if (j<i):
                s[j]=words[j]
            else:
                s[j]=words[j+1]

        for j in range(0,N-U):
            if (s[j][0] == words[i][-1]):
                searchNextWord(s,j,U)


    words=[]
    N=int(input())
    if (N<1 or N>1000):
        exit()
    for i in range(N):
        new_element = str(input())
        words.append(new_element)

    res = [None]*N
    for i in words:
        if (len(i)>10):
            exit()

    Result = False
    for i in range(0,N):
        if (Result==False):
            searchNextWord(words, i, 0)

    if (Result==True):
        for i in range(0,N):
            print(res[i])
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Comment: It's not an endless loop, it might be caused by the algorithm itself

Answer (score 1):

too many for loops man, your program does not go endless but it takes insane amount of time to execute!

use a linked list to do it. It will take more memory per word but it will make the search much more easier. Since you are reordering the input, you will need to consider implementing a browser class that caches the pairs into a variant of a binary tree(where each node contains the start and end of the contained elements. This will reduce the passes you need to perform the search.